# flex-direction on angular component changes mysteriously

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I have an angular component that has the flex-direction set as seen in the CSS snippet below. The component is included in the template for another component with no additional styles applied (no inline styles and nothing that would cause it to be referenced in any stylesheet in the application). However, if I inspect it in the browser there are a few element styles overriding what is defined in the :host rule (see fig. 1). The first time the component is initialized the element styles are the same as the :host rule so there's no harm done. What is weird is that if the component is destroyed and then recreated (using ngIf or ngSwitch) the flex-direction on the element styles switches to "row" (see fig. 2). I know a couple of ways to work around it, but I have quite a few components where I'm experiencing this and I'm just trying to understand why this is happening.

```css
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Fig. 1

[image]

Fig. 2

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a stackblitz?

Comment: Do your project use fxFlexLayout module ?

Comment: can i see your html code ?

Comment: @Emilien I am using fxFlexLayout in the application, but when dealing with the host element of a component I just apply the styles directly as shown above.

Comment: @ConnorsFan for now I'm going with the !import suggestion. If I have any more issues I'll create a stackblitz to try and get to the bottom of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `!important` to your css lines to prevent any other changes in your flex , that is may be happening of using `flexbox` in your `HTML` file also

Comment: Thanks,this does work and seems to be the easiest work-around to implement. Still not sure how the element styles are getting applied, but this allows me to move forward.

Comment: if two identical css properties css are added, the last one will be applied (what happens in your code), but when you add `! important`, it will apply the one with the important.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, the child component doesn't replace the tag.

(i.e.`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` or `<app-component></app-component>`)

It actually creates its own hosting element at the same level, so it renders outside of the element with your desired class.

In order to tell Angular to use your class, you must add the "host" property in the component.ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector:'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrl: ['./example.component.css'],
  host: {'class': 'desired-class'}
})

export class ExampleComponent {}
```